# How do i return the new image from the function?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I added the line

```
if (newWidth >= 1 && newHeight >= 1)
```

And now i'm getting the error

Error   1   'Images_Batch_Resize.Form1.ResizeImage(string, int, int)': not all code paths return a value

```
private static Bitmap ResizeImage(String filename, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
        {
            using (Image originalImage = Image.FromFile(filename))
            {
                //Caluate new Size
                int newWidth = originalImage.Width;
                int newHeight = originalImage.Height;
                double aspectRatio = (double)originalImage.Width / (double)originalImage.Height;
                if (aspectRatio <= 1 && originalImage.Width > maxWidth)
                {
                    newWidth = maxWidth;
                    newHeight = (int)Math.Round(newWidth / aspectRatio);
                }
                else if (aspectRatio > 1 && originalImage.Height > maxHeight)
                {
                    newHeight = maxHeight;
                    newWidth = (int)Math.Round(newHeight * aspectRatio);
                }
                if (newWidth >= 1 && newHeight >= 1)
                {
                    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                    {
                        //--Quality Settings Adjust to fit your application
                        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
                        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                        g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);
                        return newImage;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you want to return if the newWidth or the newHeight are zero?

Comment: Because...what happens when that test fails?  It drops past that code block and then what?  You need a final `return` at the end...`return null;` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because the function will not always return a value. If newWidth is not >= 1 or newHeight is not >= 1, then it won't have anything to return. If it doesn't meet those requirements, you'll want to return null or something like that so you know something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You return value only in one of `if` ( in last ). Add return statement to other if or at end of this function add something like `return null`

```
private static Bitmap ResizeImage(String filename, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
    {
        using (Image originalImage = Image.FromFile(filename))
        {
            //Caluate new Size
            int newWidth = originalImage.Width;
            int newHeight = originalImage.Height;
            double aspectRatio = (double)originalImage.Width / (double)originalImage.Height;
            if (aspectRatio <= 1 && originalImage.Width > maxWidth)
            {
                newWidth = maxWidth;
                newHeight = (int)Math.Round(newWidth / aspectRatio);
            }
            else if (aspectRatio > 1 && originalImage.Height > maxHeight)
            {
                newHeight = maxHeight;
                newWidth = (int)Math.Round(newHeight * aspectRatio);

            }
            if (newWidth >= 1 && newHeight >= 1)
            {
                Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                {
                    //--Quality Settings Adjust to fit your application
                    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
                    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                    g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);
                    return newImage;
                }
            }
            return null ( or something ) 
        }
```

In your code if code don't hit last `if` it will don't return any value, but you decelerate that this method will return`Bitmap` at end so compilation want that in every case for user that function some kind of `Bitmap` will be return ( even as a `null`)